# Make something move when no key is pressed

Tags: cocos2d

I am new to game programming and I have a question about my game logic. 
In my game there is a balloon that is supposed to collect some stars. the balloon moves with the keyboard. When the balloon hovers over a star, the star will go in to the balloon. In order to do that I created a script for my balloon and added a cc.eventManager.addListener to it and in update: function (dt) I managed to move the balloon when the keyboard keys are pressed. Now my balloon works fine. Then I added some stars to my mainGame.js script, and there in update: function (dt) for the mainGame, I calculated the distance between the star and balloon, if they are close enough, the star will go into the balloon. 
Now I want to do something else. In my game there is an evil force that tries to eat the balloon, When the key is not pressed (the balloon is not moving) this evil force(at the top corner of the screen) will pull the balloon to itself (when there is at least one star in it). This means i should implement something like this:

```
var jumpUp = cc.moveTo(this.jumpDuration, evilForcePosition).easing(cc.easeCubicActionOut())
this.ballon.runAction(jumpUp);
```

but I don't know where and how to do so. I tried to put this action in update: function (dt) of mainGame.js but I got weird outcome.

My question is this: How can I force the balloon to go somewhere when the input keys are not pressed?

Here Are some codes:

This is my update function in mainGame

```
update: function (dt) {
    var ballonPos = this.ballon.getPosition();

    for (var j = 0; j< 10; j++){
        var nStar = this.stars[j];
            if(cc.pDistance(ballonPos, nStar.getPosition()) < 50){
            nStar.setPosition(ballonPos.x , ballonPos.y);
        }     
    }//end for j
 },
```

So in this script, if the balloon is close enough, the star will be attached to it and move with it in every frame.

And here is the function that governs keyboard movements in balloon.js:

```
setInputControl: function () {
    var self = this;
    // add keyboard event listener
    cc.eventManager.addListener({
        event: cc.EventListener.KEYBOARD,
        // When there is a key being pressed down, judge if it's the designated directional button and set up acceleration in the corresponding direction
        onKeyPressed: function(keyCode, event) {
            self.freeToMove = false;
            switch(keyCode) {
                case cc.KEY.a:
                    self.accLeft = true;
                    self.accRight = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.d:
                    self.accLeft = false;
                    self.accRight = true;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.w:
                    self.accTop = true;
                    self.accBot = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.s:
                    self.accTop = false;
                    self.accBot = true;

            }
        },
        // when releasing the button, stop acceleration in this direction
        onKeyReleased: function(keyCode, event) {
            self.freeToMove = true;

            switch(keyCode) {
                case cc.KEY.a:
                    self.accLeft = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.d:
                    self.accRight = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.w:
                    self.accTop = false;
                    break;
                case cc.KEY.s:
                    self.accBot = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, self.node);
},
```

And here is the update in balloon.js

```
update: function (dt) {
    if (this.accLeft) {
        this.xSpeed -= this.accel ;
    } else if (this.accRight) {
        this.xSpeed += this.accel ;
    }
    if(this.accTop){
        this.ySpeed += this.accel;
    }else if(this.accBot){
        this.ySpeed -= this.accel;
    }


    if ( Math.abs(this.xSpeed) > this.maxMoveSpeed ) {
        this.xSpeed = this.maxMoveSpeed * this.xSpeed / Math.abs(this.xSpeed);
    }
    if ( Math.abs(this.ySpeed) > this.maxMoveSpeed ) {
        this.ySpeed = this.maxMoveSpeed * this.ySpeed / Math.abs(this.ySpeed);
    }
    //move!
    this.node.x += this.xSpeed; this.xSpeed = 0;
    this.node.y += this.ySpeed; this.ySpeed = 0;



 },
```

Comment: I'd say it's hard to know *where* until you post all relevant code (not sure how much there is). We generally discourage pages and pages of code here, but a reasonable amount should give an idea.

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I have edited the post, I hope that I provided enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something to happen at the moment when the player stops giving input, you can add a "`inputTime`" field that stores the time of the last input. For the keyboard, you could check if the player has released all the relevant keys, for example.

The code to do that can be placed in `EventListener` for keyboard, but you can also do it in `update`. If none of the `acc*` fields is set, it means that currently there is no input. You can update `inputTime` as long as there is input.

Additionally, in `update` you would check how much time has passed since the last update of `inputTime` (by comparing the current time to the time stored in `inputTime`). If *some* time has passed you can apply your custom logic for that situation.

How much is *some*? The technical lower bound depends on the clock resolution and update frequency, the practical lower bound is on how fast humans type... yet, actually, it depends on your game. So, I suggest to experiment with this value.

Answer (score 1):

> Making something move when no key is pressed

is generally down to either AI or physics.

Your stars gravitate toward the balloon - this is a physics-like effect and should be factored out of `update()` into a function called from `update()`, e.g. `for (star in stars) star.doPhysics()` which should contain this existing code:

`if(cc.pDistance(ballonPos, nStar.getPosition()) < 50){
            nStar.setPosition(ballonPos.x , ballonPos.y);`

Evil force is like a spirit, I think? So you may want to treat as some kind of AI, in which case call `evilForce.think()`. This method then holds logic to control where the evil force goes... this would probably be called every `update()` but I don't know cocos2d; maybe it's just called on a single event.

As opposed to `doPhysics()` and `think()` you could just use a single generic method name `act()`.  At this stage in your project, it's all the same and keeps things easier to remember. You can always change / differentiate these, later on. This would  allow you to run through *all* entities (stars, balloon, spirits) and just call `entity.Act()`.